Explicit deletion causes move assignment operator to participate in overload resolution
According to 12.4.1.8 in C++20 standard,

A defaulted move special member function (11.4.4.2, 11.4.5) that is defined as deleted is excluded from the
set of candidate functions in all contexts.

the erroring line should use the copy assignment operator. However it still went for the deleted move assignment operator. Is there somewhere else in the standard that explains this behavior? This behavior is seen in gcc13 (13.3.0) compiler.
Interestingly, if I remove the explicit deletion, the code compiles fine.
struct foo {
    foo() = default;
    foo(const foo&) = default;
    foo(int a) : a(a) { }
    
    foo& operator=(const foo& other) {
        return *this;
    }
    
    foo& operator=(foo&& other) = delete;
    int a;
};

int main()
{
    foo f, g;
    f = 1; // Failed to compile due to "error: use of deleted function ‘foo& foo::operator=(foo&&)’"
    return 0;
}


You missed the key part of the quote.  The quote only applies to A defaulted move special member function  Which you do not have, you have just a straight up deleted move operator.  Pretty sure what the quote is talking about is where you have a defaulted move operation but it can't be defined because of a class member not allowing it so it gets defined as deleted instead.

Thanks. I saw a similar explanation in another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518368/is-implicitly-deleted-constructor-delete-or-not-declared-at-all

You have found the difference between declared as deleted, which you have done, and defined as deleted, which is something the compiler can do (when a move is not possible).
